# add class to element if user is not logged in

Tags: users, login, session, logout

Please help . I need to add class to this button if user is not logged in

```php
<?php echo apply_filters( 'my_order_html', '<button type="submit" class="ADD-CLASS-HERE cfw-primary-btn cfw-next-tab validate" name="my_list_html" id="place_order" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '"><span class="cfw-button-text">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</span></button>' ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
```

Comment: where is that code? WooCommerce dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope, you should ask this in a WooCommerce community or via their official support routes

Comment: its not woocommerce question

Comment: I just need to add class to a button if user not logged in

Comment: it's part of a WooCommerce filter, you edited out `woocommerce_order_button_html` etc, you can see it in the edit history. I'd suggest looking up filters and hooks as you may need to use them depending on where the code is located, but it's still a WooCommerce question, you should ask WooCommerce users how to modify a button in a WooCommerce filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this and implement it in your own case

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   $extraClass = "hide-button";
} else {
   $extraClass = "";
}
?>

<a class="<?php echo $extraClass;? href="#">">Button text</a>
```

and give the new class a styling like "display: none;" or something

Comment: Thank you very much @Richardo